# How can I configure my router to assign two static IPs to my computer?

Tags: networking, router, ip, ip-address, ipv4

How can I configure my router to assign two static IPs to my Computer? My router is a D-Link DIR-825ACG1 AC1200 Router. And my PC is running Ubuntu 20.10.

When I go into my routers LAN settings, I am able to assign one ip address to my computer.

But, if I try to assign one more IP address to my computer, I get this error saying: *MAC address is already used.*

And I am also not able to assign any ranges like 192.168.0.3/30, and I do not know how ranges work.

Please help me on this. I am unable to find anything on the internet that helps me with this issue.

Comment: why are you trying to assign public IP to your computer, you should be using private IPs for internal network https://superuser.com/questions/479617/local-vs-internet-ip-addresses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DHCP standard doesn't allow multiple IPs for one MAC address.

If you want to have multiple IPs on the same interface, you need to add the second IP on the client manually.

You can either add both IPs on the computer manually or have one over DHCP and set the second one statically on the client, but DHCP only issues one IP per MAC address.

If you want to have both IPs issued by DHCP to the same NIC, you would need to request one IP and then change the MAC address of the NIC and request the second IP.

Something like that is described here: [Getting 2 IP addresses on one network card, using DHCP](https://superuser.com/questions/344733/getting-2-ip-addresses-on-one-network-card-using-dhcp)

Comment: You can add multiple IPs on your computer manually, just add IP alias to the card https://superuser.com/questions/679134/add-a-static-ip-alias-to-a-dhcp-interface-on-windows-8-and-above https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fb44d9bf-b6ce-4126-8a32-c6823aee2b4d/setup-two-ips-on-the-same-pc-with-one-network-adapter?forum=win10itpronetworking

Answer (score 1):

**DHCP will only assign one IP address per MAC address.**

So if you want two IP addresses and don’t want to assign them manually you somehow need to add another Ethernet port to your PC.

Manual assignments of an IP address is typically the only way to get two IP address to share the same physical connection.

If you don’t want to handle it manually, you can always add another Ethernet port to the PC via some kind of expansion card. Either a PCI card or even a USB to Ethernet dongle. Once you do that you have another physical connection that is identified by a specific MAC address and you can then assign an IP address to that MAC address on the router.

This is actually the cleanest and simplest way to do this if you don’t want to get “in the weeds” on manual IP setup or MAC address assignment hacks.